# Passing multiple functions to a template

Tags: c++, templates

The following code doesn't compile:

```
template< typename Fn1, typename Fn2 >  
bool templateFunctionOne( Fn1&& fn1, Fn2&& fn2 )
{
   int v = 5;
   fn1( v );
   return fn2( v );
}

template < typename Fn1, typename Fn2 >
bool templateFunctionTwo( Fn1&& fn1, Fn2&& fn2 )
{
   std::future< bool > tk( std::async( std::launch::async,
                           &templateFunctionOne< typename std::remove_reference<Fn1>::type, 
                                                 typename std::remove_reference<Fn2>::type >,
                           std::forward<Fn1>(fn1),
                           std::forward<Fn2>(fn2) ) );
    return tk.get();
 }

 bool printThis( int value ) 
 {
    cout << "this value = "
         << value
         << endl;
    return true;
  }

 bool printThat( int value )
 {
    cout << "that value = "
         << value
         << endl;
    return true;
  }

  int main()
  {
     auto func1 = std::bind( &printThis, std::placeholders::_1 );
     auto func2 = std::bind( &printThat, std::placeholders::_2 );
     return templateFunctionTwo( func1, func2 );  
  }
```

I'm getting errors like these:

```
error: no match for call to '(std::_Bind<boo (*(std::_Placeholder<2>))(int)>) (int&)'  
return fn2( thatValue );  
       ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~  
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = bool (*)(int); _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<2>}]  
operator()(_Args&&... --args) cont  
^~~~~~~~
```

I know it has something to do with passing multiple function pointers to the template, but just don't know where and what. Could anyone help point out where my mistakes are please?

Comment: Your second `bind` call creates a function object expecting two arguments; it ignores the first and passes the second to `printThat`. But `templateFunctionOne` calls it with one argument. You likely meant `std::placeholders::_1` in both places. In fact, you can drop `bind` calls and just pass `printThis` and `printThat` directly.

Comment: `auto func2 = std::bind( &printThat, std::placeholders::_2 );` -> `auto func2 = std::bind( &printThat, std::placeholders::_1 );`

Comment: Thank you Mathieu, that was it!! Greatly appreciate it!

Comment: All the merit rests with @IgorTandetnik

Comment: Works best with return 0;

Answer (score 0):

Stop using std bind.

```
 return templateFunctionTwo( &printThis, &printThat );
```

every use of it in the above code makes your code less clear and more error prone.

This is also a mess:

```
&templateFunctionOne< typename std::remove_reference<Fn1>::type, 
                                             typename std::remove_reference<Fn2>::type >,
                       std::forward<Fn1>(fn1),
                       std::forward<Fn2>(fn2)
```

why not

```
[fn1=std::forward<Fn1>(fn1),fn2=std::forward<Fn2>(fn2)]()mutable{ templateFunctionOne(std::move(fn1), std::move(fn2)); }
```